# Dockerfile configuration for apache serving django project

Tags: python, django, docker

Currently i'm trying to deploy my django app via docker.

I just started to learn the hole thing, so now I want to build an image based on httpd official image that creates new blank django project (just to try) and serves it by apache. (I am using ubuntu 18)

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM httpd

RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y 

RUN apt-get remove --purge apache2 apache2-utils \
    && apt-get install -y --reinstall apache2 apache2-utils

RUN apt-get install -y libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3

RUN apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip python3-venv

RUN mkdir /home/django_project
ENV VIRTUAL_ENV=/home/django_project/venv
RUN python3 -m venv $VIRTUAL_ENV
ENV PATH="$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"

WORKDIR /home/django_project
RUN . venv/bin/activate \
    && pip install django==2.1 \
    && django-admin startproject new \
    && chown :www-data new/
RUN . venv/bin/activate && python new/manage.py migrate
RUN chown :www-data new/db.sqlite3 && chmod 664 new/db.sqlite3

COPY django-site.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/django-site.conf
RUN a2ensite django-site.conf && a2dissite 000-default.conf && a2dissite default-ssl.conf

EXPOSE 80
```

And django-site.conf (apache configuration for new site):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /static "/home/django_project/new/static"
    Alias /media "/home/django_project/new/media"

    <Directory "/home/django_project/new/static">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory "/home/django_project/new/media">
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory "/home/django_project/new/new">
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIScriptAlias / "/home/django_project/new/new/wsgi.py"
    WSGIDaemonProcess example.com python-path="/home/django_project/new" python-home="/home/django_project/venv/bin/python3"
    WSGIProcessGroup example.com

</VirtualHost>
```

after building an image with `docker build -t a2 .` and running it by `docker container run -p 80:80 a2` all i get is "It works!" on http://172.17.0.2/(container's IP)
Container output:

```
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Thu Aug 01 10:14:33.602426 2019] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 1:tid 140462335452288] AH00489: Apache/2.4.39 (Unix) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Aug 01 10:14:33.602644 2019] [core:notice] [pid 1:tid 140462335452288] AH00094: Command line: 'httpd -D FOREGROUND'
```

Please, help! What am i doing wrong!? Honestly, I tried everything what I could think of. I googled, but nothing helped, and most answers point in different directions.

P.S. I also tried to google different options to deploy django sites, but it seems like there is no analytics on this matter. So, can you share your ways of deploying and their pros and cons.

Comment: Have you checked any of these threads: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/197289/setting-servername-to-suppress-apache-warning-message-with-multiple-domains or https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/155150/where-in-apache-2-do-you-set-the-servername-directive-globally

Comment: If you look inside the container, what do you see at path `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled`?

Comment: and python home should be python-home="/home/django_project/venv/bin/python<Version>" I think

Comment: I changed python-home="/home/django_project/venv/bin/python3", but nothing changed. At /etc/apache2/sites-enabled there is only one file - django-site.conf with my code. And that is what i don't understand: what brings to life "It works!" if default site is off!?

Comment: And i don't think the real problem is with ServerName, althou i tried to fix it as suggested above - it didn't work (from inside the container), but on the web they say it's just warning message, not an error...